# No Suitable Method Found To Override

Tags: c#

How to fix this problem?
Error   1

> 'WindowsApplication2.Form4.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to
>   override  C:\Users\%USER%\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form4.Designer.cs 14  33  WindowsFormsApplication3

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw58wzka(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) does

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you rename the form in the *Form4.cs* file?

Check your class names on those two files. They should be something like:

**Form4.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormApplication3
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
```

**Form4.designer.cs**

```
namespace WindowsFormApplication3
{
    partial class Form4
```

Comment: Awesome.  I'd appreciate it if you marked my post as the answer; I'm pretty new to the site and I'd like to be able to help out more.

Comment: For me it was the namespace that got changed, not the class name.