# no suitable method found to override when converting from vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, .net

I am migrating from a vb.net application to c#, I used [this](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx) tool to convert all of my code method by method. But when I finally compiled the code and I get no suitable method found to override.

I looked at this similar post [No Suitable Method Found To Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838242/no-suitable-method-found-to-override)

but he uses partial class but I am using an internal class 
frmMain.cs Code

```
namespace RSCWebPoll
{
    internal class frmMain : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
    const bool IsDebug = false;

        const short LoopTimeInSeconds = 300;

        public TFSUtilities.Logger logger = new TFSUtilities.Logger();
        public System.DateTime NextPollTime;
        public string WinDSSStoreName;
        public string WinDSSStoreNumber;
        public string WinDSSStoreCity;
        public string WinDSSStoreState;
        public string WinDSSRegisterNumber;
        public string WinDSSTillNumber;
        public string WinDSSDrawerNumber = "1";
        public short RegisterStatus;
        public string TillSeqType;
}
}
```

frmMain.Designer.cs

```
partial class frmMain
{
    #region "Windows Form Designer generated code "
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
    public frmMain()
        : base()
    {
        //This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

any help is much appreciated...
[image]

Comment: I suspect your partial classes are in different namespaces so they are not getting linked together.

Comment: Yeah, your frmMain.Designer.cs doesn't have a namespace, as pasted into this question.  Did you monkey around with that file?  It's generated by VS, so you shouldn't touch it.

Comment: The namespace and form class needs to be the same in the cs file and the designer.cs file.  Also the default namespace in the project settings have to match the names space in the cs files.

Comment: @DStanley your right, I made sure they are the same but now I am getting Error 47 Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'namespace.frmMain'; another partial declaration of this type exists on the frmMain.cs

Comment: @Will yes I did accidently delete it but then I recreated another c# project with the same name and I attached that designer back to this project so I am guessing that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your class names of those two files.it will be like below

formx.cs

```
namespace WindowsFormx
{
    public partial class formx: Form
```

formx.designer.cs

```
namespace WindowsFormx
{
    partial class formx
```

Check namespace of designer.cs

Comment: I have checked that already but I am using a internal class in the form.cs and partial class in form.designer.cs

Comment: Both class should be partial then only it can build as a single class